# Wordpress custom plugin error - Warning: Undefined array key "home_team"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

i created custom plugin few years ago and now i have in my admin plugin page error Warning: Undefined array key "home_team" ....

Here is my code:

```
 function DBP_insert_data()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'funstar_league';


    $DBP_home = $_POST['home_team'];
    $DBP_guest = $_POST['guest_team'];
    $DBP_home_team_url_logo = $_POST['home_team_url_logo'];
    $DBP_guest_team_url_logo = $_POST['guest_team_url_logo'];
    $DBP_home_team_url_logo = $_POST['home_team_url_logo'];
    $DBP_url = $_POST['url'];
    $DBP_place = $_POST['place'];
    $DBP_time = $_POST['game_time'];
    $DBP_date = $_POST['game_date'];





    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'home_team' => $DBP_home,
                'guest_team' => $DBP_guest,
                'home_team_url_logo' => $DBP_home_team_url_logo,
                'guest_team_url_logo' => $DBP_guest_team_url_logo,
                'url' => $DBP_url,
                'place' => $DBP_place,
                'game_time' => $DBP_time,
                'game_date' => $DBP_date,
            ),
            array(
                '%s', // Use string format
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
            )

        );
    }
}
```

Here is error post:

Warning: Undefined array key "home_team" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 133

Warning: Undefined array key "guest_team" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 134

Warning: Undefined array key "home_team_url_logo" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 135

Warning: Undefined array key "guest_team_url_logo" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 136

Warning: Undefined array key "home_team_url_logo" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 137

Warning: Undefined array key "url" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 138

Warning: Undefined array key "place" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 139

Warning: Undefined array key "game_time" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 140

Warning: Undefined array key "game_date" in /Users/tomasvalach/www/fun_2/wp-content/plugins/extraliga/extraliga_insert_file.php on line 141

Comment: The mentioned keys do not exist in `$_POST`, aka they are not send with the post request.

Comment: When is `DBP_insert_data()` invoked? If it is called on every request then sure some request may not have a `$_POST` variable set. Try to set your variables once you have checked for the save variabel in `if (isset($_POST['save']))`. This may still cause some future issues as a lot of forms may use this post variable to indicate a save.

Comment: Hi thank you, can you write me some example?